# ¿Qué consulta debo utilizar para mostrar los hijos de un padre, en lugar de los hijos de todos los padres?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9

[image: Los datos que se encuentran en mi base de datos][image: Esta es mi base de datos][image: **** Tengo insertada 19 tipos de maquinarias, mi objetivo es que se muestre los equipos registrados en cada maquinaria, lo cual no lo hace, me esta mostrando todos los equipos registrados]

Tengo insertados 19 tipos de maquinarias. Mi objetivo es que se muestren los equipos registrados en cada maquinaria, lo cual no lo hace: me está mostrando todos los equipos registrados.

Esta es mi función *create*. No sé si esté mal mi código.

```
public function create(Request $request)
   {
        $machineries=machinery::pluck('name','id')->all();
        $equipments = Equipment::where("machinery_id",4)->get();//Equipment::pluck('name','id')->all();
        $areas=area::pluck('name','id')->all();
        return view('admin.equipment.child.create',compact('areas','machineries','equipments'));
   }
```

Así es como se encuentra mi modelo:

```
public function scopeAllEquipmentChild($query)
    {
    return EquipmentChild::with('machinery', 'equipment')
            ->leftjoin('equipment','equipment_children.equipment_id','=','equipment.id')
                ->join('machineries','equipment.machinery_id','=','machineries.id')
                    ->select('equipment_children.*','equipment_children.id','equipment.machinery_id','machineries.area_id')                  
                     ->get();
    }
```

Comment: Hola, Bienvenid@ al Sitio, veo que eres nuev@ te recomendaria hacer el [tour] para que conoscas mejor el sitio, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Comment: nos hace falta la estructura de la Base de datos...

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 listo brother ahi subi la BD

Comment: gracias por el esquema, pero eso no es la base de datos intenta con esta herramienta: http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 checale ahi

Comment: no eso no nos sirve necesitamos un minimo a ver si podemos reproducir lo que buscas... y con imagenes no podemos reproducir el escenarios ...

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 ok gracias

Comment: El código y los mensajes de error siempre _como texto, con formato_. No todos pueden ver las imágenes. Revisá por qué subir solo imágenes [es mala idea](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976). Por cierto, no agregues texto de párrafo en la imagen... ¡Ese texto debería ser una descripción de la imagen, para cuando la imagen no carga! Por algo la ayuda dice _La palabra entre corchetes es el texto alternativo, que se muestra si el navegador no puede mostrar la imagen. Asegúrate de incluir un texto alternativo con sentido para el software de lectura en pantalla._